# Matching from dictionaries based on sum of multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries as follows. One for services and the other for suppliers who can do the service. Each service can be provided by multiple suppliers.

```
service = {'service1': {'serviceId': 's0001', 'cost': 220},
           'service2': {'serviceId': 's0002', 'cost': 130}....}

supplier = {'supplier1': {'supplierId': 'sup1', 'bid': 30},
           'supplier2': {'supplierId': 'sup2', 'bid': 12},
            'supplier3': {'supplierId': 'sup3', 'bid': 30}....}
```

I want to have a new dictionary of matching services to suppliers based on the sum of multiple bids is greater than or equal the cost of service. Something Like:

```
matched = {'service1': [sup1, sup2, sup100],
'service2': [sup20, sup64, sup200, sup224]....}
```

Assuming we have huge number of entries in both dictionaries, what is a good way for such required matching? no restrictions on the number of suppliers that can provide a single service.
I tired the following but did not work.

```
match = {}

for key, value in service.items():
        if service[key]['cost'] >= supplier[key]['bid']:
            match[key] = [sup for sup in supplier[key]['supplierID']]
```

Here is the expected output:

```
matched = {'service1': [sup1, sup2, sup100], 'service2': [sup20, sup64, sup200, sup224]....}
```

Comment: Could you add an input - expected output pair?

Comment: Here is the expected output:

    `matched = {'service1': [sup1, sup2, sup100],
    'service2': [sup20, sup64, sup200, sup224]....}`

Comment: Do the keys in supplier are correct? Do you mean supplier = {'service1:'{...}}?

Comment: They are right. Each dictionary does have its own keys.

Comment: I am not following how services and suppliers correspond. Or is just that any supplier can provide any service and the only comparison is whether or not `cost` is greater than or equal to `bid`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Multiple bids when aggregated (sum) can pay for the service. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `we have huge number of entries in both dictionaries`. This is how I would approach the problem:

```
import numpy as np

# data
service = {'service1': {'serviceId': 's0001', 'cost': 12},
           'service2': {'serviceId': 's0002', 'cost': 30}}
supplier = {'supplier1': {'supplierId': 'sup1', 'bid': 30},
            'supplier2': {'supplierId': 'sup2', 'bid': 12},
            'supplier3': {'supplierId': 'sup3', 'bid': 30}}

# lists of suppliers' IDs and bids
sups, bids = list(), list()
for key, info in supplier.items():
    sups.append(info['supplierId'])
    bids.append(info['bid'])

# sorted lists of suppliers' IDs and bids to allow binary search
bids, sups = zip(*sorted(zip(bids, sups)))

# main loop
matched = dict()
for key, info in service.items():
    matched[key] = sups[:np.searchsorted(bids, info['cost'], side='right')]
```

`matched`:

```
{'service1': ('sup2',), 'service2': ('sup2', 'sup1', 'sup3')}
```

This code does not implement easy handling of new entries but allows to do so. For every new `service_record` we have to perform a single binary search, for every new `supplier_record` we have to perform a single binary search and a loop over `service` to update `matched`.

The code may be and should be improved depending on the specific requirements and the way you use to store the data.